# How to check if the page is hanging or taking more than usual time in karate ui automation?

Tags: karate, ui-automation

After submitting some elements the page gets hanged. So can I verify it if it is taking more time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation on waits: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#wait-api

So you can expect Karate to fail the test if an element does not appear within a particular time.

You can also do time calculations manually: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#commonly-needed-utilities

```
* def getTime = function(){ return java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() }
* def startTime = getTime()
* java.lang.Thread.sleep(100)
* def endTime = getTime()
* def elapsedTime = endTime - startTime
* print 'elapsed:', elapsedTime, 'milliseconds'
```